# monero wallet and RingCT

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringct

When will the monero wallet and ringct be completed for monero users and will the wallet be compatible with other cryptocurrencies like BTC ETH etc?

Answer (score 4):

The monero wallet with optional RingCT transactions will be available in January (RingCT transactions are available on TestNet on the current wallet). RingCT will be mandatory in the next hard fork after that.

You might mean the official GUI wallet. This will be released when it is done and there is no timeline.

Monero is quite a bit different from other cryptocurrencies so no, the wallet is most certainly not compatible with other currencies. You may be thinking of some multicurrency wallets which may soon include monero; we have no information when these will be available either.

Comment: Just one note: the ringCT is already impemented in v0.10 and just waiting for activation in Jan. As such, the transition will be seamless for those running v0.10 now.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer - rCT will be optional in January hard fork and mandatory the one after that.